# Imaginary part of complex number, nothing works?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I want to find the imaginary part of the complex number (a+i*b).

say I have a function in the following form:

```
((-2 + 4 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (2 - I) Sin[0.0628319 z])/
((1 + 2 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (4 + 2 I) Sin[0.0628319 z])
```

where $z$ is a real number variable. I want to reform the function into (a+i*b) form.

---

attempt:

if I do `Im`, then it wil give me the following output:

```
Im[((-2 + 4 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (2 - I) Sin[
    0.0628319 z])/((1 + 2 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (4 + 2 I) Sin[
    0.0628319 z])]
```

but this is not what I want.

Comment: Consider tugging `// ComplexExpand // Simplify` on the end.

Comment: If you know that `z` is a real number, then do `ComplexExpand[Im[ ... ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not tryng to get the imaginary part of a number. You are trying to get the imaginary part of an expression. Let's say we define your expression to be equivalent to eq:

```
eq==(2 + 4 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (2 - I) Sin[0.0628319 z])/
((1 + 2 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (4 + 2 I) Sin[0.0628319 z])
```

Solving the above for z gives 4 solutions. Lets say we take one of them and try a full simplify on it. We would get a fraction whose denominator has a real and an imaginary part. (I'm working via the cloud so I'll paste the result as InputForm:

```
ArcCos[((5.322525763080274 - 
9.01827480722634*I) - 
    (20.816270607258474 - 2.3058885477431663*I)*eq)/
   Sqrt[(159. + 288.*I) + eq*((-392. + 16.*I) + 481.*eq)]]
```

This expression cannot be split between the real and imaginary parts because they are intertwined. Mathematica would give you a nice z=a+b*I but it can't. Therefore it uses Im[...] because it cannot decompose it any further.

Try assigning value ranges for eq and finding the limits on z for the different values. Do bear in mind that eq is by definition a complex number too.

Comment: Please don't forget to format your code blocks in markdown; see [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
func[z_] := ((-2 + 4 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (2 - I) Sin[
  0.0628319 z])/((1 + 2 I) Cos[0.0628319 z] + (4 + 2 I) Sin[
  0.0628319 z])
ComplexExpand@func[0]
Show[
 Plot[
  Im@func[z],
  {z, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Blue
  ],
 Plot[
  Re@func[z],
  {z, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red
  ], PlotRange -> All
]

(*1.2 + 1.6 I*)
```

[image]